# Is there information about developing tibco custom palette elements?

Tags: java, tibco, businessworks

I need to develop a generic entry point for tibco business works based on convention over configuration. Common wsdl that maps our internal complex data model schema in the form of key value approach. I need to develop a palette element that accepts requests and map them in a AESchema objects inside. I have searching about this kind of development with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, extending the palettes of TIBCO Designer is possible, but TIBCO will not tell you how to do it. If I were you I'd stick to the supported features. You can put the mapper processes in a project library, to be imported in all projects. If you use XSDs instead of AESchemas, you can also use XSLT for mapping.